# Ubuntu20 headless xfce slow response on VNC

Tags: xfce, vnc, headless

I have installed `Ubuntu20` on `intel NUC`. I have also installed VNC on it so that I can access this machine at client site from my office. I have to operate it without monitor, so as soon as I unplug hdmi monitor from it, vnc shows it as black screen. So I have installed `xfce` on it and switched to xfce desktop instead of default ubuntu desktop.

Now I can access it via vnc and no black screen is showing up. But the response is very slow. If I open terminal, it takes 2-3 sec to load and when I type any command it again takes 2-3 sec to show up. It is very slow. How can I make it smooth in operation. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you installed Ubuntu Core 20?   Xubuntu and XFCE are available only in *deb* packages which cannot run on a *snap* only 20 release; but require you to be using a *year.month* or *deb* based normal product not specialist *year* based products.

Comment: @guiverc Sorry I didn't get you. I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 desktop and then installed xfce using `apt-get install xfce4`. After that I switched to xfce session

Comment: Did you connect to VNC via a local network or via a RealVNC account?

Comment: Please correct your question, Ubuntu has had *year* formatted products since 2016 - they are *snap* only and cannot use *deb* packages.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Using realvnc account

Comment: @SAndrew RealVNC account can be slow because it transfers the data through their servers. Use a direct VNC connection instead.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Ubuntu is at different location and we are not connected to same network so have to use real vnc